# C while loop using scanf prints twice when entering more than 1 char of input

Tags: c, while-loop, stdin

I'm trying to read input from stdin in C, where the program performs a few tasks if the entered character is any key but "enter". I'm using a while loop, and it works fine when user only enters 1 char, but prints a line twice when they enter more than that (entering more than 1 char is fine, the program should generate a new number per each one -- so like if the user enters 'aaa', it generates 3 new numbers.)

So this is the ideal output after entering something like 'eeee'(and it works fine when you enter just one char):

```
CallList: I22 U55 U52 L1
enter any key for call (q to quit, no enter):
```

but this is what actually happens when you enter 'eeee':

```
enter any key for call (q to quit, no enter): CallList: I22 U55 U52 L1
enter any key for call (q to quit, no enter):
```

and this is the part of my code (minimal reproducible version):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){

system("clear");
  printf ("CallList: \n");
  printf("enter any key for call (q to quit, no enter): ");
char c;
  scanf(" %c", &c);
  system("clear");

char quit = 'q';
  int random;
  srand(1063);

  while (c != quit){

    if (c != '\n') {
      random = rand() % 75 + 1;
      // does a few functions here, they don't print anything and don't use stdin
     }
    printf ("CallList: ");
    // prints the call list here
    printf("\n");
    printf("enter any key for call (q to quit, no enter): ");
    scanf(" %c", &c);
    system("clear");
    }
printf("Goodbye! \n");
  exit(0);

}
```

what is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Consider reading some chapters of the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) and if allowed, use [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). If permitted use the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Comment: Behavior of the terminal is OS specific. On Linux, see [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and [pty(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html). If allowed, use [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you for your comment! I used gdb's online debugger and it doesn't say anything while running but when I enter q (exit 0), it says: 0x00007ffff7ed9142 in __GI___libc_read (fd=0, buf=0x5555555596b0, nbytes=1024)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
26      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c: No such file or directory." and I have no idea  what that means

Comment: You may need to spend *days* in reading books about programming on Linux. These books are printed on paper. Spend hours in reading documentation of GCC and of GDB

Comment: There may be problem with scanf function, consider using getline instead.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the assignment is due tonight, AMAZING

Comment: Prepare yourself to fail the assignment. On Linux lines are buffered. For the next assignment, consider using [GTK](http://gtk.org/). If allowed, study -for inspiration- the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: @T0maas thank you for your comment! unfortunately it made no difference, still having the same problem

Comment: Or try getchar() it will take only one character from stdin buffer in one iteration. But getchar also captures \n and \r, so you must filter this in `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your loop:

```
    while (c != quit){
 
        if (c != '\n') {
            random = rand() % 75 + 1;
            //here you can add things to your calllist
            c = getchar();
        }
        else {
            printf ("CallList: ");
            // prints the call list here
            printf("\n");
            printf("enter any key for call (q to quit, no enter): ");
 
            c = getchar();
            system("clear");
        }
    }
```